# Importing Maya module into Nuke (Python)

Tags: python, import, maya, nuke

I can import the maya module with ease through the Python 2.7 IDE, but when working with Nuke's script editor, I cannot import Maya and get a "No module named maya" error

Any help?

Comment: Perhaps 'Nuke's script editor' isn't checking the correct Python installation (whichever version has Maya installed)? This is a vague question.

Answer (score 1):

well if you want to import maya modules you can add the path of "E:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2013\Python\Lib\site-packages" to your sys.path in nuke,

here is an explanation how to do it ..

first test the paths if its their by using the code below

```
import sys
[each for each in sys.path]
```

now in this list you can either insert in the beginning or append the path of your maya modules at the end by this line of code(**the path below is in my case will be different on your computer**)

```
sys.path.append("E:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2013/Python/Lib/site-packages")
```

when you are adding the path check with your slash should be either // or **/** ...

then again test if the path is added by using the code i give you in the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the system module, you can append a path with the nuke module itself:

```
nuke.pluginAddPath('C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2016/Python/Lib/site-packages/')
```

And to test:

```
import maya
```